# R Passing linear model to another function inside a function

Tags: r, scoping, mass-package

I am trying to find the optimal "lambda" parameter for the Box-Cox transformation.

I am using the implementation from the **MASS** package, so I only need to create the model and extract the lambda.

Here is the code for the function:

```
library(MASS)

find_lambda <- function(x) {
  # Function to find the best lambda for the Box-Cox transform

  my_tmp <- data.frame(x = x) # Create a temporary data frame, to use it with the lm
  str(my_tmp) # Gives the expected output

  the_lm <- lm(x ~ 1, data = my_tmp) # Creates the linear model, no error here
  print(summary(the_lm)) # Prints the summary, as expected

  out <- boxcox(the_lm, plotit=FALSE) # Gives the error

  best_lambda <- out$x[which.max(out$y)] # Extracting the best fitting lambda
  return(best_lambda)
}

find_lambda(runif(100))
```

It gives the following error:

```
Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'my_tmp' not found
```

The interesting thing is that the very same code is working outside the function. In other words, for some reason, the **boxcox** function from the **MASS** package is looking for the variable in the global environment.

I don't really understand, what exactly is going on... Do you have any ideas?

P.S. I do not provide a software/hardware specification, since this error was sucessfully replicated on a number of my friends' laptops.

P.P.S. I have found the way to solve the initial problem in the **forecast** package, but I still would like to know, why this code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boxcox` cannot find your data. This maybe because of some scoping issue.
You can feed data in to `boxcox` function.

```
find_lambda <- function(x) {
  # Function to find the best lambda for the Box-Cox transform

  my_tmp <- data.frame(x = x) # Create a temporary data frame, to use it with the lm
  str(my_tmp) # Gives the expected output

  the_lm <- lm(x ~ 1, data = my_tmp) # Creates the linear model, no error here
  print(summary(the_lm)) # Prints the summary, as expected

  out <- boxcox(the_lm, plotit=FALSE, data = my_tmp) # feed data in here

  best_lambda <- out$x[which.max(out$y)] # Extracting the best fitting lambda
  return(best_lambda)
}

find_lambda(runif(100))
```

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes user contributed packages don't always do a great job tracking the environments where calls were executed when manipulating functions calls. The quickest fix for you would be to change the line from

```
the_lm <- lm(x ~ 1, data = my_tmp)
```

to

```
the_lm <- lm(x ~ 1, data = my_tmp, y=True, qr=True)
```

Because if the `y` and `qr` are not requested from the `lm` call, the `boxcox` function tries to re-run `lm` with those parameters via an `update` call and things get mucked up inside a function scope.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't let box-cox do the fitting?

```
find_lambda <- function(x) {
  # Function to find the best lambda for the Box-Cox transform

  my_tmp <- data.frame(x = x) # Create a temporary data frame, to use it with the lm

  out <- boxcox(x ~ 1, data = my_tmp, plotit=FALSE) # Gives the error

  best_lambda <- out$x[which.max(out$y)] # Extracting the best fitting lambda
  return(best_lambda)
}
```

I think your scoping issue is with `update.default` which calls `eval(call, parent.frame())` and `my_tmp` doesn't exist in the `boxcox` environment. Please correct me if I'm wrong on this.